# react-sortable-hoc rows are not sort using arraymove

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, jquery-ui-sortable, react-sortable-hoc

I am trying to create a sortable list with the react.js library "react-sortable-hoc"

link: https://github.com/clauderic/react-sortable-hoc

I want to do sorting the `rows` in reorder but `rows` are not sorting using `arraymove`.

What should i do? Please guide me.

codesandox code link here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-shadow-3t0qv

Screenshot:

[Form UI page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7qaR.png)

[Form data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mtki.png)

Hope this help you !

Comment: Hi Can you tell me the `solution`? (https://stackoverflow.com/users/2482400/evgeny-sorokin) (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144098/gvfordo) (https://stackoverflow.com/users/5928186/shubham-khatri) (https://stackoverflow.com/users/3122938/pankaj-gadhiya) (https://stackoverflow.com/users/10149510/brian-adams) (https://stackoverflow.com/users/8585168/igor-pavlenko)

Comment: Make a codesandox, don't create a code snippet that doesn't work.

Comment: ok sure i share it  (https://stackoverflow.com/users/894065/lux)

Comment: codesandox link : https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-shadow-3t0qv (https://stackoverflow.com/users/894065/lux)

Comment: have get the codesandox  code ? (https://stackoverflow.com/users/894065/lux)

Answer (score 0):

```
 npm install array-move@2.2.1
```

Pleas try this package:

```
 import arrayMove from "array-move";
```